# How to update Mongodb structure from string to object?

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework

I need to update image string to object, my old code is :

Scala :

```
case class Property (
  id: ObjectId = new ObjectId,
  image: String,
  description: String
)
```

Mongodb :

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5412b438e864b9afc27dcd43"),
   "_t": "models.Property",
   "image": "http: \/\/img.com\/8i0\/v1jj24e5by8nz4dy2bh6nnespw1i",
   "description": "image"
}
```

Now my updates are :

Scala :

```
case class Image (
  imageUrl: String, 
  isHosted: Boolean, 
  imageThumbUrl: String, 
  imageMediumUrl: String
)

case class Property (
  id: ObjectId = new ObjectId,
  image: Image,
  description: String
)
```

But when I do this, I'm getting [Exception: class models.Property requires value for 'image']
this is due to old db structure, is there a query way to convert old data to new structure or 
what code should I add to adopt to new structure changes? Please help, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is not because of your old db structure. [MongoDB is schemaless](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/), two documents can have a totally different structure. The problem originates from somewhere in your code.

Comment: Hi @MarkusWMahlberg Thanks for the reply. But when my db property collection is empty, this code worked.

Comment: Again, MongoDB does not enforce document structure. There isn't even a mechanism for that.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg thanks again with the reply, in that case, do you have any clue what code adjustment should I do? Thanks again

Comment: You most likely have to debug, as I assume you checked the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer is to update your db using JS, if you guys have different way pls post it here. Thanks :

```
function () {  
   var cursor = db.property.find();
   var property;
   while ( cursor.hasNext() ) {
      property = cursor.next();

      if(typeof property['image'] == 'string' || property['image'] instanceof String){

    db.property.update({_id: property['_id']}, { $set:{ "image":{"isHosted": false, "imageUrl": property['image'], "imageMediumUrl": "", "imageThumbUrl": "" } } });

      } 

   }

}
```